# Display Table with heading in Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have been trying to display a table in my nativescript mobile application,i got the output but the user interface is not as expected.

My .html file:

```
<ScrollView>
 <StackLayout *ngIf="this.bool">
  <GridLayout columns="17*,16*,12*,16*,7*,20*,12*" rows="auto">
   <Label text="Start Time" col="1" row="0" ></Label>
   <Label text="End Time" col="3" row="0"></Label>
   <Label text="Period" col="5" row="0" margin-top="50"></Label>
  </GridLayout>
 <template *ngFor="let col of this.rows; let i=index">
  <GridLayout columns="11*,14*,1*,14*,14*,1*,14*,20*,10*,11*" rows="auto">
   <TextField [(ngModel)]="col.Start_Hour" col="1" row="0" ></TextField>
   <Label text=":" col="2" row="0" ></Label>
   <TextField [(ngModel)]="col.Start_Minute" col="3" row="0" ></TextField>

   <TextField [(ngModel)]="col.End_Hour" col="4" row="0" ></TextField>
   <Label text=":" col="5" row="0" ng-readonly="checked"></Label>
   <TextField [(ngModel)]="col.End_Minute" col="6" row="0"></TextField>

   <TextField [(ngModel)]="col.Subject_Id" col="7" row="0"></TextField>
   <StackLayout (tap)="remove(i)" col="8" row="0"><Image src="~/images/minus.png" height="30" width="30" col="3" row="0"></Image></StackLayout>
  </GridLayout>
 </template>
 </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ans my .ts file contains an array:

```
this.rows=[{
"End_Minute": "28",
"Class_Id": "1000",
"End_Hour": "13",
"Start_Hour": "11",
"Sequence": "1",
"Start_Minute": "19",
"Subject_Id": "300"
}, {
"End_Minute": "36",
"Class_Id": "1000",
"End_Hour": "28",
"Start_Hour": "10",
"Sequence": "1",
"Start_Minute": "28",
"Subject_Id": "3000"
}, {
"End_Minute": "30",
"Class_Id": "1000",
"End_Hour": "12",
"Start_Hour": "11",
"Sequence": "3",
"Start_Minute": "10",
"Subject_Id": "3000"
}, {
"End_Minute": "15",
"Class_Id": "1000",
"End_Hour": "12",
"Start_Hour": "11",
"Sequence": "4",
"Start_Minute": "13",
"Subject_Id": "300"
}]
```

the output I am getting is :
[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBqzm.png)

I have a doubt that why is that colon (:) going above in the row and why am I getting spaces between the textfield and the colon?
can anyone please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

There are some default alignment (horizontal and vertical) that gets applied depending on the UI elements and the platform (iOS/Android). To get consistent behavior, it's probably better to specify specifically the alignment on the template.

Below is the updated html code (look for `horizontalAlignment` and `verticalAlignment`):

```html
<ScrollView>
 <StackLayout *ngIf="this.bool">
  <GridLayout columns="17*,16*,12*,16*,7*,20*,12*" rows="auto">
   <Label text="Start Time" col="1" row="0" ></Label>
   <Label text="End Time" col="3" row="0"></Label>
   <Label text="Period" col="5" row="0" margin-top="50"></Label>
  </GridLayout>
 <template *ngFor="let col of this.rows; let i=index">
  <GridLayout columns="11*,14*,1*,14*,14*,1*,14*,20*,10*,11*" rows="auto">
   <TextField verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="right" [(ngModel)]="col.Start_Hour" col="1" row="0" ></TextField>
   <Label verticalAlignment="center" text=":" col="2" row="0" ></Label>
   <TextField verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="left" [(ngModel)]="col.Start_Minute" col="3" row="0" ></TextField>

   <TextField verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="right" [(ngModel)]="col.End_Hour" col="4" row="0" ></TextField>
   <Label verticalAlignment="center" text=":" col="5" row="0" ng-readonly="checked"></Label>
   <TextField verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="left" [(ngModel)]="col.End_Minute" col="6" row="0"></TextField>

   <TextField [(ngModel)]="col.Subject_Id" col="7" row="0"></TextField>
   <StackLayout (tap)="remove(i)" col="8" row="0"><Image src="~/images/minus.png" height="30" width="30" col="3" row="0"></Image></StackLayout>
  </GridLayout>
 </template>
 </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: hi, thank you for responding, by adding verticalAlignment and horizontalAlignment my problem solved if I use a label there, but it still exists if I am using TextField